# How to retrieve column names in other languages with CSOM?

Tags: column, csom

I am trying to retrieve display name of a column in all languages available in my SharePoint installation (currently English and German).

```
internal static void TestColumn(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field field)
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.InternalName);
    Console.WriteLine(field.Title)
}
```

The code above will produce the following:

```
Modified_x0020_By
Document Modified By
```

How to retrieve column names in other languages?

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned code

```
 field.TitleResource.GetValueForUICulture(cultureName)
```